# Getting a custom variable by dot notation

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to access to a custom variable through dot notation (or bracket) instead of doing the `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` methods? In example (I know it's not the best way):

```js
let darkColor = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--dark-color'); 
console.log(darkColor)
```

```css
:root {
  --dark-color: black;
}
```

Is there any way to dont use those methods and write something like `document.documentElement.style['--dark-color']`? (this one doesn't work, but just for getting the idea).
I am curious at it because you can access to regular attributes like `color` or `background-color` through the dot notation but not for custom variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the applied custom properties only using `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue`.

`element.style[someProperty]` and `getComputedStyle(element)[someProperty]` are not equivalent.

`element.style` gives you the property directly assigned to the element (not what is currently applied, which can be different).

And your `:root { --dark-color: black; }` is applied through the stylesheet and not at the element directly.

`getComputedStyle` returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` where the values of the properties reflect the result of all applied rules. To get the correct custom property you need `getComputedStyle`, so you can't get rid of that.

For `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(name)` compared to `getComputedStyle(element)[name]` part.

The dot notation or array access is not possible for custom properties. That access is given by this part of the specification:

> For each CSS property `property` that is a **supported CSS property**, the following partial interface applies where camel-cased attribute is obtained by running the CSS property to IDL attribute algorithm for `property`.
>
> ```
> partial interface CSSStyleDeclaration {  
>   [CEReactions] attribute [LegacyNullToEmptyString] CSSOMString 
>   _camel_cased_attribute;
> };
> ```
>
> The camel-cased attribute `attribute`, on getting, must return the result of invoking `getPropertyValue()` with the argument being the result of running the IDL attribute to CSS property algorithm for camel-cased attribute.

And **supported CSS property** is specified as:

> […] The term **supported CSS property*** refers to a CSS property that the user agent implements, including any vendor-prefixed properties, **but excluding custom properties**. […]